# The pushforward measure of a Radon measure is also a Radon measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be two locally compact Hausdorff spaces that are also $\sigma$-compact, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map. If $\mu$ is an unsigned Radon measure on $X$, show that the pushforward measure $f_*\mu(E):=\mu(f^{-1}(E))$ is a Radon measure on Y.

I need to verify that $f_*\mu$ satisfies the three properties of a Randon measure, that is

- Local finiteness
- Outer regularity
- Inner regularity

I have difficulty doing this. For local finiteness, suppose that $K$ is a compact subset  of $Y$, I need to show that $f_*\mu(K)=\mu(f^{-1}(K))$ is finite, but $f^{-1}(K)$ may not be compact.

Comment: What you want to show is false. Consider the constant map $f: x \mapsto x_0$ and assume that $\mu$ is locally finite, but not finite.

Comment: @PhoemueX Good counterexample. The claim is not right, but can we still say something about $f_*\mu$,? such as outer regularity or inner regularity.